# Django and Nginx set-up doesn't serve static files

Tags: django, nginx

My Django-Nginx set up mysteriously stopped serving static files to my site after a reboot. The site seems to be hosting fine, but I am given a '404' error when my site tries to serve CSS files and other static content.

"CoolBlog" is the name of the project, 'Blog' is the name of an app.

**Directory Tree:**

```
site.mywebsite.com
|
├── database
│   └── db.sqlite3
├── source
│   ├── blog
│   ├── CoolBlog
│   ├── functional_tests.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── static
├── static
│   ├── admin
│   ├── bootstrap-4.3.1-dist
│   ├── css
│   └── styles.css
└── virtualenv
    ├── bin
    └── lib
```

**Relevant section from CoolBlog/settings.py:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Sites-Available/site.mywebsite.com:**

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name site.mywebsite.com;

    location /source/static {
        alias /home/elspeth/sites/site.mywebsite.com/static;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/site.mywebsite.com.socket;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

**Software/OS versions:**

- Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- Django 2.1.7
- nginx/1.10.3
- Gunicorn 19

I'd really appreciate advice about how to proceed.

Comment: Just to confirm, is Debug set to False?

Comment: Yes. Debug is set to False.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `./manage.py collectstatic`
2. An example for django+gunicorn+nginx config:https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html

   ```
   server {
       server_name www.site.com;
       client_max_body_size 5M;
       location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

       location /static {
           alias /home/caocao/coding/caocao/static;
       }

       location /media {
           alias /home/caocao/coding/caocao/media;
       }

       location / {
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_pass http://unix:/home/caocao/coding/caocao/gunicorn.sock;
       }

       listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
       ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
       include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
       ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
   }
   ```